# How do I use C++ <filesystem> in Visual Studio Express 2013?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, c++14

I have been trying to use the C++ 14 experimental filesystem feature in VS Express 2013 without success. If I add the following line the code compiles;

```
#include <filesystem>
```

After adding the following;

```
using std::tr2::sys;
```

the code does note compile and gives following error message:

```
Error   1   error C2873: 'std::tr2::sys' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
```

How correctly can I use the filesystem. Tried to visit http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh874694 and could not find a clear explanation of how to use it.

Comment: And what errors do you get? For what code?

Comment: @MikeSeymour: that does not work. Also see this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/06/06/c-14-stl-features-fixes-and-breaking-changes-in-visual-studio-14-ctp1.aspx

Comment: Isn't it `using namespace std::tr2::sys` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
using std::tr2::sys;
```

Use the right syntax:

```
using namespace std::tr2::sys;
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Was wondering why one can do "using std::string;" but not "using std::tr2::sys;"

Comment: I believe `using std::string` imports a class (`string`) whereas `using namespace std::tr2::sys` imports a whole namespace. They are for different things.

Comment: @Amani If that is the answers to your question, then consider accepting it.

Comment: @ta.speot.is: To be precise, `using ns::X` imports an identifier. Could be a class, could be anything else with a name. `using namespace NS` imports every identifier inside that namespace.